# How to split one kist into several arrays and sum separate in thymleaf?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

in the cycle 6 values ​​need to be sum and displayed in table 3 then 2 and 1.  #aggregates.sum -sum all array

```
       <tr th:each="detail, iter : ${item.mill}" th:unless="${iter.index > 2}">
                <td th:text="${detail.silLevel}" class="text-right"></td>
                <td th:text="${detail.endRest}" class="text-right"></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I am not entirely clear what you are asking here. Can you edit your question so that it shows us some input data, and the expected output, based on that data? (And "kist" should be "list", right?).

Comment: You can do some [basic arithmetic](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#aggregates) using Thymeleaf - but generally I would say you are better off doing this before you hand data over to Thymeleaf.

Comment: How to sum multiple values ​​from a loop?
sum 3 vulues
total
sum 2 vulues
total